# Is there an auto refreshing graphical text file reader?

Tags: monitoring, text

So, is there a graphical text reader or editor that automatically refreshes its text if the file is completely changed outside of it?

I found that `gedit` detects file changes but refresh is not automatic, requiring interaction.

Also, `evince` could do it but does not work with plain text files.

Comment: FWIW `kate` also requires interaction.

Answer (score 0):

**Sublime text2** is a very good editor which will suit your requirements.

Refer to the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697056/sublime-text-2-how-to-cause-livereload-refresh-when-the-currently-edited-file) question. I have used it in windows though not in Linux environment. However, I see from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) that it is available for Linux systems too.

Comment: I am making a script that will use it and as Sublime is paid, ppl may not want to buy it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using `evince`, it is a bit slow hack, I would rather prefer a plain text reader..

basically, put this on a loop that check if the text file changed:

```
enscript -f "Times-Roman14" "TextFileThatChanges.txt" -p "ConvertedTo.pdf"
```

The font option is just to make it more readable.

`evince` will automatically detect and reload the changed pdf file!